# XML converter handle EmptyList

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I'm trying to use the simpleframework converter to convert this XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dvds generator="$Id: dvd.tpl 855 2008-08-04 15:53:24Z glapierre $"></dvds>
```

To those classes :

```
@Root
public class SearchResult {
    @Attribute(name = "generator")
    private String generator;
    @ElementList(entry = "dvd", inline = true, required = false, empty = true)
    private List<DVDResult> dvds;

    public SearchResult() {}

    public List<DVDResult> getDVDs() {
        return dvds;
    }

    public String getGenerator() {
        return generator;
    }
}

@Root
public class DVDResult { 
    // Some @Element with getters 
}
```

When the list is not empty there is no problem but in this particular case I get a `org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeException: Document has no root element` and I really don't know why.

I thought that it was on my `@ElementList` so I had `entry` and `empty` but no changes. I also removed `name` from `@Root`s.

Does somebody have an answer to that?

Comment: may be just initialize `dvds` with empty `ArrayList`

Comment: Thanks for the clue but it didn't work. It gives me the same error.

Comment: Did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640756/parsing-an-xml-stream-with-no-root-element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was my parsing which was over-complicated. I was using the SimpleXML factory, changed it to :

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
SearchResult result = serializer.read(SearchResult.class, myXMLString);
```