# deserialize a json array using xstream

Tags: java, json, deserialization, xstream

There is a lot information at stackoverflow about how  to deserialize a json array using Gson.

But how can I do the same using `XStream` with jettison?

Here is json:

```
{"entity":[{"id":"1", "name":"aaa"}, {"id":"2", "name":"bbb"}]}
```

Here is `XStream` code how I try to parse it:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
xstream.alias("entity", Entity[].class);
return (Entity[])xstream.fromXML(jsonString);
```

I have following exception:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: id : id
```

Comment: I like XStream very much. You can see I'm ranked as the 6th user at the XStream answer tag. I tried to solve your problem using XStream all the ways I could think of and I have failed. There is another thread listing other libraries to work with JSON here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java . I am sorry!

Comment: Were you able to get this working? Did you try:
`xstream.alias("entity", Entity.class);` with
`xstream.addImplicitCollection(Entity.class, "entity");` and using a `List` instead of an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With array I cannot get it running, but with a list:

Java:

```
package de.mosst.spielwiese;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.json.JettisonMappedXmlDriver;

import lombok.Data;

public class XStreamDeserializeJsonWithJettison {

    @Test
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void smokeTest() {
        InputStream file = XStreamDeserializeJsonWithJettison.class.getResourceAsStream("XStreamDeserializeJsonWithJettison.json");
        XStream xStream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
        xStream.processAnnotations(Entity.class);

        List<Entity> entities = (List<Entity>) xStream.fromXML(file);
        System.out.println(entities);
    }

    @Data
    @lombok.AllArgsConstructor
    @XStreamAlias("entity")
    class Entity {
        String id;
        String name;
    }
}
```

XML:

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "entity": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "odin"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "dwa"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from [this answer related to root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263356/xstream-parse-json-with-no-root-node) **XStream** fails when there is not root element in JSON.

Once you map *entity* to certain Java class XStream cannot find root element for pairs of *id* and *name* (as in JSON they are not enclosed in element).

Only hand-made wrapper, manipulating input streams or using custom converter can help here.